# Endless loop in ASM x86_64 with JNE

Tags: loops, assembly, x86-64, nasm

I have this simple x86_64 (Intel) assembly code, but for some reason the JNE always jumps to the label **loop1**, thus resulting in a infinity loop. I've tried to search everywhere about loops, but didn't found anything useful. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
section .data
  x dd 0
  buffer times 2 dd 0
section .text
  global _start
_print:
  mov ecx, [rbx]
  mov [x], ecx
  mov rax, 1
  mov rdi, 1
  mov rsi, x
  mov rdx, 1
  syscall
  ret
_start:
  mov rbx, buffer           ; Store buffer's pointer in RBX
  add dword [rbx], 4        ; Add 4 to buffer's first element
  add rbx, 1                ; Go to the next element (second element)
  add dword [rbx], 48       ; Add 48 to the second element
  sub rbx, 1                ; Go back to previous element (first element)
loop1:
  add rbx, 1                ; Go to the next element (second element)       
  add dword [rbx], 1        ; Add one to the element
  call _print               ; Print the element
  sub rbx, 1                ; Go back to the previous element (first element)
  sub dword [rbx], 1        ; Subtract from the element
  cmp dword [rbx], 0        ; Compare element with 0
  jne loop1                 ; If element is different from 0, go back to the loop1 label
  mov rax, 60               ; Exit program
  mov rdi, 0
  syscall
```

Comment: A dword element is 4 bytes long, not 1 byte.  So your `add rbx, 1` and such should be `add rbx, 4` and likewise for `sub rbx, 1`.

Comment: It worked, thanks!

Comment: @alfred Also consider using indexed addressing instead of constantly manipulating `rbx`.